# Identify false outlets on a river network

Tags: grass-gis, saga, flow

I have a river network that is very poorly defined (lots of gaps).  I need to identify all the false outlets.  The picture below provides an example of one of these false outlets.  The image shows that the flow path (yellow) ends ubrubtly (circled in red), it is these end point I need to identify.

I can already identify all the outlets (last point in a reach that is not a junction) but I'm not sure how I approach defining if it is a true outlet or a false outlet. I have access to python, QGIS, GRASS and SAGA.

[image]

Comment: Networkx Python module designed for this.